# Histogram bin-to-bin fluctuations - Python

Tags: python, random, statistics, histogram

If I want to keep my bin-to-bin fluctuations less than <= 5%, how do I find the maximum number
of bins I should use?

I am using an list of 10,000 random numbers to see analyze its histogram distribution.

Here is an example:
I am using the same data but with different bin sizes.
[Bin of size 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARmFM.png)

[Bin of size 50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU8Sq.png)

[Bin of size 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvFMH.png)

So I basically want to find the maximum bin size for which the distribution fluctuations between adjacent bins are within 5% of each other.

Comment: Can you add an example histogram and explain what goes wrong?

Comment: Easy to answer for uniform random numbers. But that's probably not what you really want to create a histogram from? Imagine you have 10'000 numbers in the range 0...1 and one or two numbers above 1000. How are you currently creating the histogram bins, and what is the problem with that?